# javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception

Tags: java

Getting javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception error on server but working on localhost, any help ?

Comment: Please provide more information to get some answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So far, we don't even know what's going on.

Comment: Please post some code..